# How to make a full height vertical line between first sidebar and main content in Drupal?

Tags: css, drupal-7

I found several questions on Stack Overflow regarding this. But not finding solution wrt Drupal. I want to make a horizontal line between first sidebar and main content in Drupal 7. I tried to do by making the border-right but the resulted height is just the height of the block of the first sidebar. I tried to do by position:absolute, by inserting `<div></div>` in the `page.tpl.php`, but with that the vertical line overflows on other elements when page gets refresh, so it looks bad.

The vertical line should not depend on the height of sidebar or main content. it should be just stretched from top to bottom, and should accommodate if the page gets longer or shorter, like shown in image.

[image: For image click here]

See also https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/185576/7233

Comment: For people that don't know drupal, you could post an HTML sample of the layout that you need to address

Comment: I am totally agree with you. For normal html answer is already there on stake overflow, which I found. But in drupal it may be different to achieve. Hence very first I posted same question on Drupal Answer today in hope that, Drupal answer has the people who are familiar with drupal/css, so they may give more relevant answer. But my question put Oh hold on drupal answer, although it is more related to drupal. So by no choice I have to ended up here.

Comment: Thanks Mr. Lister for copying & pasting the image. I had lower points on Stakeoverflow so I was not able to insert the image. Hence at first time I had given the link.